# Extract the MSI from exe and cancel the auto start window

Tags: powershell

I managed to extract the MSI from the .exe using the below command. but after the extraction I am getting another popup window to start the installation. may I know how to cancel this window in automated fashion. currently I am automating the installation via PowerShell

`Start-process -FilePath $path -Argumentlist "/s /extract_all:dirpath" -Wait`

Comment: Just a guess - try to remove parameter `/s`.

Comment: tried. `/s` is required extract the msi from .exe.

Comment: Do you have a link for the documentation of the .exe parameters?